# Delete the line prior to the line containing the search pattern using linux command

Tags: shell, sed, text-parsing

I have a yaml file with words and some characters.

  `version: "5.0.0"
  migratorConfigs:
   -
    name: "SchemaMigrator"
    order: 1
    parameters:
      location: "step1"
      schema: "identity"
 -
  version: "5.1.0"
  migratorConfigs:
   -
    name: "IdentityDataCleaner"
    order: 1
    parameters:
      schema: "identity"
   -
    name: "SchemaMigrator"
    order: 2
    parameters:
      location: "step1"
      schema: "identity"
   -
    name: "RegistryDataMigrator"
    order: 6
    parameters:
      schema: "um"`

I need to remove only the dash(-) prior to `name: "RegistryDataMigrator"`. There were many dashes and I just wanted to remove the last one.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/RegistryDataMigrator[^\n]*$/!P;D' file
```

Create a two line window throughout the length of the file using the `N;...;P;D` method and do not print the first line of the window if the last line of the window contains `RegistryDataMigrator`.

Answer (score 3):

I just found this answer from

http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/sed-25-examples-to-delete-line-or.html

```
sed -i -n '/RegistryDataMigrator/{x;d;};1h;1!{x;p;};${x;p;}' /home/user1/Documents/migration.yaml
```

And it works for me!